# Having Problems Installing DotNetNuke

Tags: asp.net, sql-server, iis, dotnetnuke

I'm trying to install DotNetNuke 4.09.03 (I have the use this version). There are some problems. I'm completely unfamiliar and inexperienced with this environment (I'm a php developer), so I'm having some issues getting things setup correctly.

I have a folder in the root of my site called DotNetNuke where all the DNN installation files are located. When I navigate to mywebsite.com/DotNetNuke, I receive the follow error:

```
Server Error in '/' Application.

Configuration Error

Description: An error occurred during the processing of a configuration file required       to service this request. Please review the specific error details below and modify your configuration file appropriately. 

 Parser Error Message: It is an error to use a section registered as allowDefinition='MachineToApplication' beyond application level.  This error can be caused by a virtual directory not being configured as an application in IIS.

Source Error: 


Line 87:    <system.web>
Line 88:     <!-- Ensure validationkey is not set to AutoGenerate,IsolateApps so it    correctly supports webfarms -->
Line 89:        <machineKey
Line 90:          validationKey="AutoGenerate,IsolateApps"
Line 91:          decryptionKey="F9D1A2D3E1D3E2F7B3D9F90FF3965ABDAC304902F8D923AC"
```

---

I see that it says the error is caused because the folder isn't set as an application. With the host I am using, enom, I navigate to the DotNetNuke folder and hit "Create" under the Application section, and nothing happens. No message or anything. I am not sure what to do.

Also, when attempting to add a database for the DNN installation to use, I receive this error:

```
.Net SqlClient Data Provider

 CREATE DATABASE permission denied in database 'master'.

USE [master]
GO 

CREATE DATABASE [dnn]

GO

EXEC [dnn].[dbo].[sp_fulltext_database] @action = 'disable'
GO
```

---

I apologize if these questions are silly. I'm not familiar with the IIS environment but am tasked with setting up a website in it. Thank you all for your time. Any guidance would be very appreciated.

Comment: Make sure to set the appropriate permissions on the folders. You need the application pool's user to have access and, possibly, IUSR or IIS_IUSRS

Comment: edited tags: removed asp-classic, substituted asp.net

Answer (score 0):

First problem, if you have a folder under your website root, this folder should be converted to an application (this is not required if you install donetnuke in the root). To do this, go to the IIS Manager, expand your web site, and right click the folder where you installed DNN, the select "Convert to Application" from the context menu.

Second problem, your SQL user don't have the rights to create database, give the user the appropriate permissions, the easiest way to do this is using SQL Server Management Studio, give this user the dbcreator role. (Or to keep it simple, just create the database using SA, you can do this and use in the web.config a different user for the connection)